# Python3 upgrade or install?

Tags: upgrade, python

A 16.04 system returns:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
python2 --version
Python 2.7.12
```

If the goal is to migrate to a newer version (3.8.0). I am sensing that 3.5.2 is not 'updated' to 3.8 and that the newer version is simply installed and two versions co-exist?  Is this correct or does installing 3.8 retire 3.5?

I would like to understand (before doing anything to bork-up my machine),does installing 3.8:

1. auto-magically removed & retire 3.5.2?
2. if 3.5.2 is not automatically removed, what problems will I have with  3.5 & 3.8 on the same machine??
3. if 3.5.2 is not automatically removed and I remove, will I break any dependencies?
4. what is the best practice?
5. if 3.5 **and** 3.8 is installed,  which version will be invoked when invoking the `python3`command?

With respect to question 3: I read that removing Python 2.7 from OSX causes major problems as OSX expect 2.7 to be available.  Because of this, I am hesitant to remove any version of Python from an OS without asking a few questions.

Apparently it is not unusual to have two major revisions of python (typically 2.x & 3.x), however, I am not inclined to keep more than one version of 3.x.  Specifically I am not inclined to keep 3.5.2 and 3.8 on the Ubuntu.

Comment: I prefer to be cautious and keep the default Python 3.x version alongside Python 3.8 and switch back and forth when necessary using update-alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say using software like Pyenv is a good idea for your case. 3.8 isn't in 16.04, but PPAs like Deadsnakes provide it. 
Pyenv allows you to manage multiple python versions. Check it out at 
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

run `curl https://pyenv.run | bash` in your terminal, and open a new terminal. `sudo mv $(which python3) $(which python3).5` Will make python3.5 launch python 3.5 instead of python3
 Now run `pyenv install *`. Finally, `pyenv global *`.

the asterisk (*) = run `pyenv install --list`, find the version you want to install, replace * with that.

## Sources:

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv (pyenv)

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer (how to install it)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147420/what-is-in-a-command

EDIT: Added sources, replaced where with which as where is ZSH only

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  Please add a reference link if possible to show more details

Comment: Alright! I'll add them now.